# ghost.py 0.2.3 TimeoutError: Unable to load requested page

Tags: javascript, python, html, dom, web-scraping

I'm on ghost.py Version: 0.2.3
I want to get the value of a javascript variable within a web page.
When I run this simple script, I get an error "Unable to load requested page" :

```
from ghost import Ghost
    ghost = Ghost()

with ghost.start() as session:
    page, extra_resources = session.open("http://www.offi.fr/concerts/les-3-arts-3305/belle-epoque-944532.html")
    js_variable, _ = session.evaluate('map.mapUrl', expect_loading=True)
    print js_variable
```

Here the result within ipython :

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TimeoutError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-19-3c24eef8745a> in <module>()
      1 with ghost.start() as session:
      2         page, extra_resources = session.open("http://www.offi.fr/concerts/les-3-arts-3305/belle-epoque-944532.html")
----> 3         js_variable, _ = session.evaluate('map.mapUrl', expect_loading=True)
      4         print js_variable
      5 

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ghost/ghost.pyc in wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs)
    179             func(self, *args, **kwargs)
    180             return self.wait_for_page_loaded(
--> 181                 timeout=kwargs.pop('timeout', None))
    182         return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
    183     return wrapper

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ghost/ghost.pyc in wait_for_page_loaded(self, timeout)
   1194         """
   1195         self.wait_for(lambda: self.loaded,
-> 1196                       'Unable to load requested page', timeout)
   1197         resources = self._release_last_resources()
   1198         page = None

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ghost/ghost.pyc in wait_for(self, condition, timeout_message, timeout)
   1172         while not condition():
   1173             if time.time() > (started_at + timeout):
-> 1174                 raise TimeoutError(timeout_message)
   1175             self.sleep()
   1176             if self.wait_callback is not None:

TimeoutError: Unable to load requested page
```

Could you help me point out where I'm wrong ? 
If there is any alternate way to get a javascript variable value ?

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, i found another solution to get a javascript variable :
with selenium/phantomJS :

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
driver.get('http://www.offi.fr/concerts/les-3-arts-3305/belle-epoque-944532.html')
driver.execute_script('return map.mapUrl')
```

But I'm still interested in a solution with ghost.py 0.2.3 :)